# For which value of $\delta$ is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x}{n(1+n^{\delta}x^{2})}$ uniformly convergent on $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

> For which value of $\delta \in (0,\infty)$ is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x}{n(1+n^{\delta}x^{2})}$ uniformly convergent on $\mathbb{R}$?

Can somebody verify my attempt, I have made quite a bit of misteps on the way but I think this should be correct:

> So I have already shown that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x}{n(1+nx^{2})}$ is uniformly convergent on all of $\mathbb{R}$. Because $n^{1/2}x < nx^2 +1$ (I showed this via a discriminant of a quadratic argument). First if $x >0$ it is clear that $\frac{x}{n(1+nx^{2})} < \frac{x}{n\cdot n^{1/2}x} = \frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$. If $x < 0$ then $$\frac{1}{n^{1/2}} < 0 < \frac{1}{nx^{2}+1} \implies \frac{x}{n(1+nx^{2})} < \frac{x}{n\cdot n^{1/2}x} = \frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$$
>
> and by the Weierstrass M-Test the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x}{n(1+nx^{2})}$ is uniformly convergent on $\mathbb{R}$.
>
> So now I plan on doing a similar strategy.
>
> We want to know when $n^{1/2}x < n^{\delta}x^{2}+1$. As then we will have $\frac{x}{n(1+n^{\delta}x^{2})}< \frac{1}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}}$. By using the discriminant of quadratics, this happens when $n-4n^{\delta}< 0$. Here we note that $1-4(1^{\delta}) < 0$, for all $\delta$. So let $n\geq 2$. This is when $\delta > \frac{-\ln(4)}{\ln(n)} + 1$. So since this need to hold for all $n\geq 2$, we need $\delta > \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{-\ln(4)}{\ln(n)}+1=1$. Since the biggest the RHS can be is when $n\to\infty$.
>
> So we conclude that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x}{n(1+n^{\delta}x^{2})}$ uniformly converges on $\mathbb{R}$ for all $\delta \in [1,\infty)$.

My main concern is if the series converges for any $\delta\in (0,1)$, as we have not compared against $1/n^p$, where $p>1$.

Comment: $n^{1/2} < nx^{2}+1$ when $0 < nx^{2}-n^{1/2}x+1$ which is for all $x$ since the discriminant is $n-4n < 0$ for all $n$. So $\frac{1}{1+nx^{2}} < \frac{1}{n^{1/2}x}$. Which part is incorrect?

Comment: I am not sure why you are using a seeming arbitrary bound $n^{-3/2}$. How about trying different bound such as $n^{-p}$ ($p>1$) as you pointed out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that we have

$$
\left| \sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty} \frac{x}{n(1+n^{\delta}x^2)} \right|
\leq \int_{N}^{\infty} \frac{|x|}{t(1+t^{\delta}x^2)} \,dt.
$$

The last integral can be computed by applying the substitution $u=x^2 t^{\delta}$. (Of course, we may exclude the trivial case $x = 0$ so that the substitution makes sense.)

$$
\int_{N}^{\infty} \frac{|x|}{t(1+t^{\delta}x^2)} \, dt
= \frac{|x|}{\delta} \int_{N^{\delta} x^2}^{\infty} \frac{du}{u(1+u)}
= \frac{|x|}{\delta}\log\left( 1+\frac{1}{N^{\delta} x^2} \right).
$$

It is easy to check that

$$ f(x) = \begin{cases}
x\log(1+x^{-2}), & x \neq 0 \\
0, & x = 0
\end{cases}$$

is uniformly bounded on $\mathbb{R}$. Let $C > 0$ be any bound of $f$. Then

$$ \forall x \in \mathbb{R} \ : \quad \left| \sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty} \frac{x}{n(1+n^{\delta}x^2)} \right|
\leq \frac{|f(N^{\delta/2} x)|}{\delta N^{\delta/2}} \leq \frac{C}{\delta N^{\delta/2}} $$

This tells that the series converges uniformly for all $\delta > 0$.

Comment: You really do like integrals

Answer (score 3):

By completing the square one easily obtains the following inequality  $$\frac{2n^{\delta /2}\lvert{ x\rvert} }{1+n^{\delta}x^{2}}\leq 1 $$

Hence for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$, we get
$$\frac{1}{n}\frac{\lvert x \rvert}{1+ n^{\delta}x^{2}}\leq \frac{1}{2n^{1+\delta /2 }} $$
Now since $\delta >0$ the uniform convergence follows from Weierstrass M-test.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea works for any $\delta >0$. We have $$1+n^{\delta} x^{2} \geq 2n^{\delta /2} x$$ hence $$ \frac x {n(1+n^{\delta} x^{2})}\leq \frac 1 {2n^{1+\delta/2}}$$ I have taken $x>0$ in this proof but it is obviously enogh to consider this case.

Comment: So many typos you are lucky to have been upvoted...